# Using the same javascript library several times in an ebook

Tags: html, apple-books

I would like to develop responsive ebooks, and lucky me I found that iBook Author allows to include javascript in the books. This works through inserting the HTML widget in a small box to the text.

What is the best practice when one uses the same javascript code again and again inside the book? What if I would like to use e.g. d3.js several times to create figures? Do I need to insert it every single time to the given page, inside the given widget? Can I reuse parts of the code, store d3.js in some place, so all the widgets can use that piece of code several times on different pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is to store your .js script in a folder labelled JavaScript inside the .oebps folder, then have your HTML point to that script / directory whenever you need to employ it. I have to confess though that I did not understand most if your question with the 'tiny boxes' and such.